# Silverlight for Windows phone 7 - two text blocks after each other with NO linebreak

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm relatively new to Windows Phone 7 development, so bear with me on this.

I've two text blocks, each with binding to two different properties, like this:

```
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
```

So when I deploy this code, on the phone it will be something like this:

```
6
This is a title
```

I want the text to be displayed this way instead:

```
6: This is a title
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three most common UI layout elements are StackPanel, Grid & Canvas. Here's one way..

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock .. />
    <TextBlock .. />
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: This seems to work right now, but above it is suggested that horizontal stackpanel could cause margin problems later on. Hm..

Comment: This seems to be the best solution after all :)

Answer (score 4):

```
 <TextBlock>
     <Run Text="{Binding ID}" />: 
     <Run Text="{Binding Title}"/>
 </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Using Run is the better way of doing this - if you use a Horizontal StackPanel then you'll discover that later you have problems with Margins

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure you can't use Binding with the Run property because it is not a DependencyProperty.

Comment: +1.  Its close enough.  However the ": " between ID and Title needs to be implemented as `<Run Text=": " />` so that the space after the colon appears in the output.

Comment: Thanks for help, but looks like the binding in Run is giving a XamlParseException (AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_UNKNOWN_ERROR). Tested with no binding but static text. That worked. So I guess, is @avanek onto something?

Comment: @Rupal: Which .NET version are you using, I think Run.Text is DP only since 4.0.

Comment: I think I chose 3.5. So that could be it. How am I able to change the target net framework in this project? I don't anything in "properties" in VS2010 where I can do this. Thanks!

Comment: @Rupal Project properties -> Application tab -> Target framework

Comment: @commanderz That is actually not possible to do - I guess because this is a mobile/silverlight app? I don't have this option there! :S

Comment: Found a blog post around this, that seems to describe the same problem: http://lescriv.blogspot.com/2010/09/windows-phone-7-silverlight-binding.html

Comment: @Rupal, ah, I forgot you are in Silverlight, you may be forced to use the StackPanel from the other answer after all. Sorry.

Comment: @Rupal I know I've had issues with using binding on the Run property with WP7 before as well - that's why I mentioned it. I've used the answer you marked as accepted as the workaround before. I wish that WP7 would get up to speed with Silverlight 4 because it can be painful to remember what works in which versions.

Comment: @avanek Yes agreed, even though I'm just a beginner with WP7